# Calculating time remaining and elapsed

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0

I am writing a method to help me calculate time for task.
Each task has to be finished within number of hours from creation.

Desired behaviour:
 I need to display number of ours left to complete the task.
 Positive number there is time left
 Negative number the task overrun the time specified.

**Is this correct implementation for calculating time difference?**

So far my progress is this and I have created couple tests:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Displays number of hours left for resolution as positive and negative number for missed targets.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="createdTime"></param>
    /// <param name="closedDateTime"></param>
    /// <param name="resolutionTime"></param>
    /// <returns>Timespan</returns>
    public static TimeSpan GetNumberOfHoursLeftToResolution(DateTime createdTime, DateTime? closedDateTime, long resolutionTime)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var diff = new TimeSpan(0);
        bool isNegative = false;

        var startWithResolutionHours = createdTime.AddTicks(resolutionTime);

        // task is closed
        if (closedDateTime.HasValue)
        {
            diff = (startWithResolutionHours - closedDateTime.Value);

            isNegative = closedDateTime.Value >= startWithResolutionHours;
        }
        else
        {
            // task is still open
            diff = (startWithResolutionHours - now );
            isNegative = now.AddTicks(resolutionTime) >= startWithResolutionHours;
        }

        var result = new TimeSpan(diff.Days, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes + ((diff.Seconds > 0) ? 1 : 0), 0);

        if (isNegative)
        {
            return -result;
        } 

        //count of all difference between times
        return result.Add(-new TimeSpan(resolutionTime));
    }
```

I have wrote couple tests

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void TaskHasNotBeenResolvedsAndHasAllTimeLeftForResolution()
        {
            var d = DateTime.Now;
            var resolutionTime = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0).Ticks; 

            var expectedResult = -new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);

            var actualResult = TimeCalculation.GetNumberOfHoursLeftToResolution(d, null, resolutionTime);

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TaskHasNotBeenResolvedAndHasFrom8Hours6Left()
        {
            var d = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);
            var resolutionTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0).Ticks;

            var expectedResult = -new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0); // 6 hours

            var actualResult = TimeCalculation.GetNumberOfHoursLeftToResolution(d, null, resolutionTime);

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TaskHasNotBeenResolvedAndHas20MinLeft()
        {
            var d = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4).AddMinutes(20);
            var resolutionTime = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0).Ticks;

            var expectedResult = -new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0); // -20min

            var actualResult = TimeCalculation.GetNumberOfHoursLeftToResolution(d, null, resolutionTime);

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TaskHasNotBeenResolvedAndHas1MinLeft()
        {
            var d = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4).AddMinutes(1);
            var resolutionTime = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0).Ticks;

            var expectedResult = - new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0); // - 1min

            var actualResult = TimeCalculation.GetNumberOfHoursLeftToResolution(d, null, resolutionTime);

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TaskHasNotBeenResolvedAndHasNoMinutesLeft()
        {
            var d = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4);
            var resolutionTime = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0).Ticks;

            var expectedResult = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0); // 0 min

            var actualResult = TimeCalculation.GetNumberOfHoursLeftToResolution(d, null, resolutionTime);

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TaskHasNotBeenResolvedInTimeOneMinOverdue()
        {
            var d = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
            var resolutionTime = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0).Ticks;

            var expectedResult = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0); // 1 min

            var actualResult = TimeCalculation.GetNumberOfHoursLeftToResolution(d, null, resolutionTime);

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it little shorter

```
    public static TimeSpan GetNumberOfHoursLeftToResolution(DateTime createdTime,
                                   DateTime? closedDateTime, long resolutionTime)
    {
        var currentPoint = closedDateTime ?? DateTime.Now;
        return new TimeSpan(resolutionTime - (currentPoint - createdTime).Ticks);
    }
```